# use pywhatkkit in same tab instead of using new

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to use `pywhatkit` to search in same tab instead of opening in new tab.I am using following code:

```
import pywhatkit as kit 
kit.search(query)
```

It open new search query in new tab instead of using current tab. if anyone knows a way to handle this problem please help.

Answer (score 1):

Creator/Author of the pywhatkit here, the library uses webbrowser module to search on Google and at this moment, for searching in the same tab you have to manually update the source code of the library.

To do so, go to Lib\site-packages\pywhatkit\mainfunctions.py and replace line number 230 with `web.open(link,new=2)`, setting new=2 opens the url in same tab. I haven't tested this so I can't assure you that this will work so better to try it by importing the webbrowser module first and doing the same then update the source code.

Comment: haven't try this yet, but I think it'll be good idea to automatically close tab after sending message.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround that I found was to alter the code from the library, and I didn't actually called the library function.

```
import time
import webbrowser as web
import pyautogui as pg
import keyboard as kb

# Open the tab and wait for it to load
web.open(f"https://web.whatsapp.com/")
time.sleep(10)

message = 'Line 1%0aLine 2'
phone_number = '+5563999999999'

# Click on Chrome address bar then wait 1 second and click again to edit
# To find coordinates you can run 
# >>> import mouseinfo
# >>> mouseinfo.MouseInfoWindow()
pg.click(1123,62)
time.sleep(1)
pg.click(1123,62)

# Type in the message, press enter, then wait page to load (8 sec) and click 
# enter again to send the message
# These times will depend on internet and computer
kb.write('/send?phone=' + str(phone_number) + '&text=' + str(message_alt))
pg.press('enter')
time.sleep(8)
pg.press('enter')
# This last pause is to run this in a loop
time.sleep(2)
```